# Are there any chrome extensions that are free to inspect and understand?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

So I have recently started working on building a Google chrome extension, and found the entire landscape fascinating to say the least. While I was checking to understand how some of these extensions work, I found that many of them have blocked 'inspect element'. I found only 'Adblock Plus' which allows it.

**My question:**

1. Are there any more complex interesting chrome extensions that allow inspection?
2. Any way to find such extensions or how to get around the ones that have blocked viewing?

> **As a beginner, I would appreciate any advice or tips in this area.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect and debug **all** extensions right in the browser.
You may need to use a different method of invoking devtools.

To inspect the popup you can enable `developer mode` switch in `chrome://extensions` and then right-click the extension's icon in the toolbar or click `...` inside the puzzle piece menu that lists all extensions, then choose `Inspect popup`.

Similarly, to inspect something shown in the tab, you can open devtools via the standard hotkeys like (F12 or Ctrl-Shift-i in PC) when the cursor is focused on the toolbar even if the page actively intercepts these hotkeys and/or the context menu.

You can also open devtools from the browser menu "More tools".

There's also `chrome://inspect`.

Comment: And here's a tutorial on debugging extensions.

Comment: Wow, thanks for mentioning `chrome://extensions`. This is exactly the perfect response. This anwer deserves more recognition.